# Пустое окно в Xamarin.Forms в проекте WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Создал приложение Xamarin.Forms, андроид версия работает нормально. Некоторые компоненты всё-таки криво подключаются, но юзер интерфейс полностью показывается, но когда я создал приложение WPF (.Net Framework 4.8) и попробовал подключить по инструкции туда netstandard2.0 проект Xamarin, высветилось пустое окно. То есть сам интерфейс приложения не отобразился.

```
public partial class MainWindow : FormsApplicationPage
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new DMXamarin.App());
    }
}
```

Я посмотрел по отладке, что WPF входит в этот проект и даже пытается пропушить в навигационный стак все окна из основного проекта, но отображения нет... только пустое окно... [image: Окно WPF]

```
<wpf:FormsApplicationPage  
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF" 
        x:Class="MediaStreamer.XamarinForms.WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MediaStreamer.XamarinForms.WPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
</wpf:FormsApplicationPage>
```

Comment: Очень странно видеть внедрение того, что предназначено для телефонов в WPF (десктоп) проекте... Ну а так, у вас же XAML пустой, в нету вообще какого-либо элемента для отображения.

Comment: @EvgenyZ, 1) у меня весь App.xaml и MainPage.xaml в проекте DMXamarin. Из него же и это окно подгрузилось с названием DMXamarin. в основном проекте и не должно быть ничего в окне, сам класс окна импортируется через метод LoadApplication () в проект WPF. 2) Xamarin – это не только мобильная разработка, это кроссплатформенный фреймворк, чтобы приложение можно было запускать и на mac, и на ios, и на android, и на windows...

Comment: Я не говорю, что "нельзя" на десктопе, я говорю, что это "странно", ибо я почти не знаю проектов, которые на Xamarin работают под Windows, особенно, через WPF обертку. К тому же, "кроссплатформенный" - это .NET5-6 (или старые .NET Core), которые имеют, например MAUI, который спокойно запускается на всем перечисленном, без всех этих костылей в виде WPF + Xamarin. По этому всему я и говорю - ваш выбор странный. Ну про сам вопрос - шапку то от Xamarin вам нарисовало, значит он успешно подгрузился в WPF, но в вашем Xamarin нет контента для отображения, а что там у вас, вы не показываете.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, там как минимум должен быть логотип Xamarin сверху (там, где сейчас просто надпись DMXamarin) - картинка должна быть... И елементы управления - текст, кнопки, всплывающее меню с выбором страниц... Как я уже говорю, на андроид оно отображается... MAUI ещё очень сырой и не до конца протестированный... Куча ошибок при портировании проектов...